# Bluemix: Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

Since Monday we can't push our Dreamfactory app to Bluemix, it always fails, error is attached below. The command used to push the app is:

```
cf push <appname> -s cflinuxfs2
```

Output:

```
-----> Downloaded app package (15M)
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack'...
Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/compile-extensions) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
Submodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out 'a4b58d8ec6acd35a5b7b6d406e21c590b5686371'
-------> Buildpack version 4.3.0
Installing Nginx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/scripts/compile.py", line 51, in <module>
    .from_build_pack('lib/additional_commands')
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py", line 189, in extensions
    process_extension(path, ctx, 'compile', process, args=[self])
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py", line 69, in process_extension
    success(getattr(extn, to_call)(*args))
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/lib/nginx/extension.py", line 39, in compile
    .package('NGINX')
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py", line 165, in package
    self._installer.install_binary(key)
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/lib/build_pack_utils/cloudfoundry.py", line 197, in install_binary
    url = self._ctx['%s_DOWNLOAD_URL' % installKey]
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py", line 151, in __getitem__
    return self.format(dict.__getitem__(self, key))
  File "/tmp/buildpacks/cf-php-build-pack/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py", line 143, in format
    newVal = val.format(**self)
KeyError: u'NGINX_16_LATEST'
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed
```

Answer (score 2):

You can push a php app on bluemix using a custom buildpack.
For new stack *cflinuxfs2* I suggest to use "**zend-server-php-buildpack-bluemix**" that include:

- Zend Server 8.5 Enterprise edition
- Zend Server 8.5 configuration files
- PHP 5.6
- Apache web server

**usage:**

- Enter the following command:

> cf push your_app_name -m 512M -s cflinuxfs2 -b
>   https://github.com/zendtech/zend-server-php-buildpack-bluemix.git

Your application is deployed using the Zend Server buildpack

regards.